# How do I open my downloaded program?

Tags: drivers, 13.10, apt

I have been trying to download a program onto my new Ubuntu but this message comes up over and over when I try to load the archive with the Archive Manager.  I can't find a way around it.  What does it mean and how do I fix the problem?

```
Archive:  /home/hans/Downloads/cfw_installer_5732_83.exe
[/home/hans/Downloads/cfw_installer_5732_83.exe]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/hans/Downloads/cfw_installer_5732_83.exe or
          /home/hans/Downloads/cfw_installer_5732_83.exe.zip, and cannot find /home/hans/Downloads/cfw_installer_5732_83.exe.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: .exe files don't run in Ubuntu. You can install wine `sudo apt-get install wine` to run them or find an ubuntu alternative from the software center.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Windows .exe file from what I can see in your question. You'd need to use a tool [like wine](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) in order to run Windows executables under Ubuntu, and even then it won't necessarily work with all programs.